# Colocar clique do botão na tecla Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alguém poderia me ajudar a colocar o click do botão na tecla `Enter` utilizando *Javascript ou Jquery*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tens de defenir um oscultador de eventos para quando uma tecla for pressionada:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
```

E depois verificar se a tecla foi o *Enter*:

```
if(e.which == 13)
```

Exemplo (com um event handler para 3 botões para verificar que é o correto):

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) $('#meuBotao').click();
});

$('button').click(function(e) {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Botão 1</button>
<button id="meuBotao">Botão 2</button>
<button>Botão 3</button>
```

Comment: @Marconi 53? (bom que pude ajudar!)

Comment: @Marconi funciona para mim. Clica em "executar o trecho de código" e carrega `Enter". Para mim dá o alert do botão 2, no Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que não tem necessidade de dar um exemplo com jquery para essa finalidade. Então segue abaixo um exemplo com Js puro.

Pra escutar eventos do DOM (página do browser), basta usar o `addEventListener('event', callback, false)`, o código abaixo fará o que você solicitou:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
       if(e.which == 13){
          console.log('a tecla enter foi pressionada');
       }
    }, false);
```

Bom, revisando o que você solicitou, você deve estar querendo enviar alguma informação do form, não?

Digamos que seja, você pode criar uma função para essa finalidade e executar dentro do listener, exemplo:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    enviaForm();
  }
}, false);

function enviaForm(){
  var nome = document.querySelector('#nome');
  var email = document.querySelector('#email');
  var password = document.querySelector('#password');
};
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.